# javascript ternary statement equivilance

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: Is “z=(x||y)” same as “z=x?x:y” for non-boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817578/javascript-is-z-xy-same-as-z-xxy-for-non-boolean)

Are the following two lines of code equivalent in javascript?

```
a = b ? b : c

a = b || c
```

I want to express: "a should be assigned b if b is truthy, otherwise a should be assigned c"

I expect they would both work exactly the same, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: so it is! I promise I searched first.

Comment: No worries, just doing what I always do :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The two are almost exactly identical.

Both will first evaluate `b`. If it's truthy, it'll return `b`. Else, it'll return `c`.

---

As pointed out by @thesystem, if you have a getter method on `b`, it'll be called twice for the ternary, but only once for the or statement.

Test it using the following snippet:

```
var o = {};
o.__defineGetter__("b", function() {
    console.log('ran');
    return true;
});

var d = o.b || o.not;

console.log('-----');

var d = o.b ? o.b : o.not;
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bqsey/

Comment: ok, thanks. javascript is weird :)

Comment: @captainclam +1 for that comment. JavaScript sure is weird.

Comment: Minor difference is that `b` is actually evaluated twice when truthy. Most cases won't make a difference.

Comment: Even more minor difference is that the `||` case has 2 less characters (assuming minification) - less info to transfer to client.

Answer (score 1):

> Logical operators are typically used with Boolean (logical) values;
>   when they are, they return a Boolean value. However, the && and ||
>   operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands,
>   so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may
>   return a non-Boolean value.

ref: [Logical Operators - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)